# Use multiple redux stores in react native app for different versions

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

We have an app built in react native which have versions e.g v1, v2. For separation of concerns we have used 2 stores, one of those gets selected based on APP_VERSION.
Problem is when user updates the app from v1 to v2 then v2 store gets selected which does not have user's data hence user gets logout. I am looking for some way to communicate between these stores or any better alternate would help a lot.

```
<Provider store={ ENV.APP_VERSION === "V2" ? v2store : v1store }>
  { ENV.APP_VERSION === "V2" ? <V2Application /> : <V1Application /> }
</Provider>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some code like this should help

```
//do the below task while at splashscreen
if (ENV.APP_VERSION === 'V2') {
  const v2storeData = v2store.getState();
  const v1storeData = v1store.getState();
  if (checkConditionIfWeHaveToPopulateV2) {
    const v1DataToPopulateInV2 = getV1DataToPopulateInV2(v1storeData);
    v2store.dipatch(populateV2(dataToPopulateInV2));
    v1store.dipatch(cleanV1());
  }
}

return (
  <Provider store={ENV.APP_VERSION === 'V2' ? v2store : v1store}>
    {ENV.APP_VERSION === 'V2' ? <V2Application /> : <V1Application />}
  </Provider>
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Although I am using redux-persist package that needed some more configuration, this approach worked for me to set foundation.